# ExternalLoginSignInAsync returning Failed response, when UserLogin exists

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have an asp.net core website built with MVC, asp.net identity and IdentityServer4.

I am able to flow through the registration process on login with google, and navigate around the secure pages. However, when I log out, and attempt to login with the Login with google functionality, the ExternalLoginCallback code for calling `var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false);` returns a `Failed` response as though the record does not exist ing my aspnetUserLogin table.

I have confirmed the token that is being passed from `info.LoginProvider`, and `info.ProviderKey` match the values in my userlogin table, so I am not sure why I am receiving a `Failed` response.

**note** I have modified the standard external registration code to create the user with the `emailconfirmed = true` value, but i still get the response described above.

Why is this `ExternalLoginSignInAsync` method returning failed when I see the data in the asp.net userlogin table?

Answer (score 0):

I would ask some questions, but don't have the rep points to leave a comment yet. However, I just struggled with and solved this issue (though the particular cause for you could be different), here are some steps I took that I'd recommend (for anyone running into similar issues, not just this post):

Ensure that in your DbContext class, where you map your UserLogin model to the table, it looks like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<YourUserLogin>(entity => {
     entity.HasKey(e => new { e.LoginProvider, e.ProviderKey });
     ...
     }
```

The order here is important, as it is how `FindByLoginAsync` locates the UserLogin record.

After that, check your UserLogin and User classes, and make sure that you are overriding the properties, assuming you are inheriting from the Identity classes:

`public partial class YourUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<string>`

For some reason when I scaffolded my db through EF, it did not override these fields; this creates a duplicate of each field, one from your class and one from the inherited class; this causes property clashes and Identity will see these values as empty. Overriding the properties fixed this issue for me.

In general, what I'd recommend is (if you are using Visual Studio) putting a breakpoint at your line `var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false);` , clear the output, then hit F10 and analyze the output; you will either see an error, or see something like EF generating a script looking for a user `where UserId is null` (i.e. if there is no UserLogin found, you will see this). And then reference the Identity github (as it is open-source) and follow through the various steps that `ExternalLoginSignInAsync` takes; you will eventually find the method it fails at and that will help tremendously.

Hope this helps.